# How to make this array key dynamic in JS

Tags: javascript

I am working on a PHP, JS site. I  need a dynamic JS array key.

```
var list = '';

for(i in data)
{
    var list += '<li><a>'+data[i].fieldname_usa+'</a></li>';
}
```

here I want the key to be dynamic

Ex: `var country = "usa"`

the key would be `fieldname_usa`

```
var country = "uk";
```

the key would be `fieldname_uk`

I am trying to achieve this by

```
 var country = "usa";
 var list += '<li><a>'+data[i].fieldname_+country+'</a></li>';
```

Because I use different databases for different countries and the filed names would be different in each country .

But seems like it process `data[i].fieldname_` as the key. so my finalist put is `undefinedusa` or `undefineduk`.

Comment: It is a multidimensional array , i loop over it   :)

Comment: Did you get data as response from your server.  Can you show us the structure of it?

Comment: hey if i hardcode the key it works fine :) , I only need to make it dynmic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a different notation with [`[]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties)

```
list += '<li><a>' + data[i]['fieldname_' + country] + '</a></li>';
```

(Please delete the `var` in front of the line. `list` is already declared and initialized.)